# Move Two characters from beginning to end of string VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a VBA script in excel that chanages an order number from having "CD" at the front to "CD" at the end so from "CD00001" to "00001CD"

Any help would be awesome. all of the order numbers are in Column B and start at row 5. please help.

What i have so far:

```
Private Sub OrderNumber_Click()
Dim Val As String
Dim EndC As Integer

EndC = Worksheets("Raw Data Upload").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To EndC
    Val = Right("B" & i, Len("B" & i) - 2) & Left("B" & i, 2)
    Range("B" & i).Value = Val
Next

End Sub
```

This replaces the order numbers with B5, B6 and so on but if i put this function into Excel itself it works fine.

Comment: what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: @QHarr - OP is wanting to use `"B" & i` as a `Range`, but currently it's being used like a `String`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, and I was not talking about you...

Comment: @DisplayName - No worries, but I do wonder what's going on in here?? First mass downvotes, now mass upvotes?  A little Twilight-Zoney in here eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
Right(Range("B" & i), Len(Range("B" & i)) - 2) & Left(Range("B" & i), 2)
```

An alternative is to set up the cell as a `Range()`:

```
Sub t()
Dim cel As Range
Dim endC As Long
endC = Worksheets("Raw Data Upload").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To endC
    Set cel = Range("B" & i)
    myVal = Right(cel, Len(cel) - 2) & Left(cel, 2)
    Range("B" & i).Value = myVal
Next
End Sub
```

Currently, when you do `Right("B" & i, Len("B" & i) - 2) & Left("B" & i, 2)`, for row 5, this becomes `Right("B5", Len("B5") - 2) & Left("B5", 2)`  then this evaluates to simply:

`Right("B5",0) & Left("B5",2)`, which is
`[nothing] & B5`, finally becoming
`B5`

Note the lack of using `B5`as a range. Instead it's being treated as a string.

(Also, I'm assuming this is to be run on the `ActiveSheet`. If not, please add the worksheet before the range, i.e. `Worksheets("Raw Data Upload").Range("B" & i)...`)

Answer (score 1):

Like this? DO you want it in column B?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OrderNumber_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim val As String
Dim EndC As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data Upload")
EndC = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To EndC

     val = ws.Cells(i, "A")

     Range("B" & i).Value = Mid$(val, 3, Len(val) - 2) & Left$(val, 2)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the Order Number is in column B and i want them to be replaced with the corrected order number in column.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim beginStr, endStr, originalStr, outputStr as string
dim rng as range

'put the below into a loop, assigning a rng to the desired cell each time

originalStr = rng.value ' Change to chosen range
beginStr = left(originalStr,2)
endStr = right(originalStr, len(originalStr) - 2)
outputStr = endStr + beginStr
Range("B" & i).Value = outputStr
```

I haven't got a copy of Excel to test this on but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub OrderNumber_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Raw Data Upload")
        For Each cell in .Range("B5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 2) & Left(cell.Value, 2)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And I’ll do the same